# How to set time zone in loguru?

Tags: python, logging, time, timezone, loguru

How can i set time zone Tashkent (UTC+5) to this code

```
from loguru import logger as lg

def setup_logger():
    format = (
        "<green>{time:YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss}</green> | "
        "<level>{level: <8}</level> | "
        "<cyan>{name}</cyan>:<cyan>{function}</cyan>:<cyan>{line}</cyan> | "
        "<level>{message}</level>"
    )
    lg.add("logs/debug.log", format=format,
           level="DEBUG", rotation="1 week", compression="zip")
```

I looked through the entire Internet, but can't find.
Please help!

I tried pendulum, datetime and other things. I think it will be real with "record" in loguru, but i can't.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on Linux, macOS, or another OS that supports IANA time zones directly (ie. not Windows), you should be able to set the `TZ` environment variable before your app starts.

```
export TZ=Asia/Tashkent
python app.py
```

Or, you can do it within the app like this:

```
import os, time
os.environ['TZ'] = 'Asia/Tashkent'
time.tzset()
```

Alternatively, you can adapt the approach from [this github issue](https://github.com/Delgan/loguru/issues/338) to update the record used in loguru:

```
def set_datetime(record):
    dt = datetime.datetime.now(ZoneInfo("Asia/Tashkent"))
    record["extra"]["datetime"] = dt

logger.configure(patcher=set_datetime)
logger.add(sys.stderr, format="{extra[datetime]} {message}")
```

This requires Python 3.9+ to use `ZoneInfo` to get the current time in a specific time zone. If needed, you can use pendulum, arrow, or pytz in older Python.